# MongoDB How To $lookup 2 documents correctly?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Sorry I'm noob,I am using lookup with two documents, here I have 3 tables:

```
const Product = {
 id: ObjectId,
 name: String
}

const user = {
 id: ObjectId,
 name: String
}

const comment = {
 id: ObjectId,
 product: ObjectId('product'),
 user: ObjectId('user'),
 parentComment: ObjectId('comment')
 text: String
}

const rate = {
 id: ObjectId,
 product: ObjectId('product'),
 user: ObjectId('user')
 rate: Number
}
```

When a user wants to see specific of a product, I show them comment and rate of the product, First I query comments than I query the user who has posted the comment and the rate value if they have rated the product, I implement lookup like this:

```
commentModel.aggregate([
                    {
                        $match:{
                            product: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.productID),
                            parent: null
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        $lookup:
                        {
                            'from': 'users',
                            'localField': 'user',
                            'foreignField': 'id',
                            'as': 'user'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $lookup:
                        {
                            'from': 'rates',
                            'pipeline': [
                                { $match: {product: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.productID), user: 'user.id'}}
                            ],
                            'as': 'rateValue'
                        }
                    }
                ])
```

The lookup first one works fine, but the rate didn't, it always return empty arrays, somebody can help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few fixes,

- You need to `$unwind` deconstruct user array because $lookup will not allow to join array field,
- to match parent collection field in lookup, you have to define variable using `let`
  in lookup,
- to match expression you need to use `$expr`

```
commentModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      product: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.productID),
      parentComment: null
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      as: "user",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "id"
    }
  },
  // add this
  { $unwind: "$user" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "rates",
      let: { userId: "$user.id" }, // add this
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            product: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.productID),
            $expr: { $eq: ["$user", "$$userId"] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "rateValue"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/siAjDBnWeHm)

---

Another option, without `$unwind`

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EwsgMj6boFL)

Comment: The first one thank you very much, it working, but the second one can you explain the `let: {
        userId: "$user"
      },`, the `$user` reference to which one? userModel or rateModel? thank you

Comment: $user id from comment model, because look at your query you are replacing user when you lookup with user `as: 'user'` but i have used `users` and user field is already there.

Answer (score 1):

You can Also try this

```
[
    {
        $match:{
            product: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.productID),
            parent: null
        },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            'from': 'users',
            'localField': 'user',
            'foreignField': 'id',
            'as': 'user'
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            'from': 'rates',
            'localField': 'user',
            'foreignField': 'user',
            'as': 'rateDetail'
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$rateDetail'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            '$rateDetail.product':mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.productID)
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks you, I was using this before, but when I try I founded that rateDetail will come to a list of the array, if user vote many products that array will be bigger, the query may be slow,  and with many users using thus query I scare it will take long